# Replace values in an xts object according to some events on specific dates in R

Tags: r, merge, xts

I have two signal series and a data series as below.

```
BuyDates<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/3/1"), by = "5 days")

SellDates<-seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/3/1"), by = "7 days")

data<- xts(c(rnorm(32,100,3)),seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/2/1"), by = "days"))
```

What i want is,the dates on which `data` gets buy signal from `BuyDates`,the value of `data` should be replaced by `1` and for `SellDates` it should be `-1`.And,on the remaining days in the sequence,1 or -1 should be carried forward till it gets the opposite signal,and for the days till the 1st signal,value should be replaced with `NA`.

kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset the `data` as usual:

```
data<- xts(rep(NA, 32),seq(as.Date("2013/1/1"), as.Date("2013/2/1"), by = "days"))
data[BuyDates] <- 1
data[SellDates] <- -1
```

Then you can carry forward the non-NA values using `na.locf`.

```
na.locf(data)
```